# Linq join get latest value from second table

Tags: .net, linq

I have two tables, let it be A and B. A is the primary table and B is the secondary. My need is to get when I join A and B the latest row from B for corresponding value of A and order by B's Primary key by using linq
    Table A
    A_id     Value 
    1      a1
    2      b1

```
Table B
B_Id   values    A_id
1    123        1
2    456        1
3    789        2
4    321        2

Result should be 

A_id  name B_Id
2   b1     4
1   a1     2
```

My current code only returns in the reverse order. I know code has some syntax error please don't consider it

```
from a in db.A
join b in db.b on a.A_Id equals b.B_Id into tem 
from b in tem.Take(1) orderby chat.Ch_IdNo descending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use `Max` instead of `OrderByDescending`/`First`, though I'm not sure which is more performant, or which would be best with SQL or EF.

So you can group join TableA to TableB and then find the maximum (latest?) B_Id from the joined group and return that.

```
var ans = from a in TableA
          join b in TableB on a.A_id equals b.A_id into bj
          let maxB_Id = bj.Max(b => b.B_Id)
          select new { a, b = bj.First(b => b.B_Id == maxB_Id) };
```

In lambda syntax:

```
var ansl = TableA.GroupJoin(TableB, a => a.A_id, b => b.A_id, (a, bj) => new { a, b = bj.First(b => b.B_Id == bj.Max(b2 => b2.B_Id)) });
```

**NOTE:** This recomputes the `Max` per member of `bj`, while the `let` uses a hidden `select` to pass the value on. You can modify the lambda to use a full body to avoid this:

```
var ansl = TableA.GroupJoin(TableB, a => a.A_id, b => b.A_id, (a, bj) => {
                                var maxB_Id = bj.Max(b2 => b2.B_Id);
                                return new { a, b = bj.First(b => b.B_Id == maxB_Id) };
                            });
```

If you are okay with `OrderByDescending` you can use group join for that as well:

```
var ans2 = from a in TableA
           join b in TableB on a.A_id equals b.A_id into bj
           select new { a, b = bj.OrderByDescending(b => b.B_Id).First() };
```

In lambda syntax:

```
var ans2l = TableA.GroupJoin(TableB, a => a.A_id, b => b.A_id, (a, bj) => new { a, b = bj.OrderByDescending(b => b.B_Id).First() });
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you didn't define it, I think with the phrase "the latest row from B for corresponding value of A" you mean that if you take all rows from B for a certain A_id, the latest one is the one with the highest value for B_Id. In your example: the row with B_Id 2 for A_Id 1, and the row with B_Id 4 for A_Id 2.

Let's do it in two steps: first I get the latest table B items per A_id, then I join them with table A:

```
var latestTableB = tableB
    .GroupBy(b => b.A_id)
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(groupElement => groupElement.B_Id)
     .First();
```

In words: group all elements of table B into groups with same A_id. Then sort all elements in the group by descending B_Id. The first element of the result will be the one with the latest B_Id

Join this with the elements of table A:

```
var result = latestTableB.Join(tableA,
   tableBElement => tableBElement.A_Id,
   tableAElement => tableAElement.A_Id,
   (b, a) => new
   {
        A_Id = b.A_Id,
        name = a.Value,
        B_Id = b.B_Id,
   });
```

In words: join the elements from latestTableB with the elements from tableA. From every element in latestTableB take the A_Id; from every element in tableA take the A_Id. When they macth, use the matching b and a from latestTableB and tableA to create one new object with the desired properties

TODO: concatenate these two statements into one

Comment: Your `latestTaableB` is missing `)` somewhere.

Comment: @harald I only need a single row from the second table that has max Id